# Modules invariant under $Hom_K(-,K)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Given a finite dimensional algebra $A$ over a field $K$ and an $A$-bimodule $M$.
Call $M$ nice in case $M \cong D(M)$ (with $D(-)=Hom_K(-,K)$) as $A$-bimodules.
A famous example is the regular module of a symmetric algebra that is nice.
Is there a classification of nice (indecomposable) modules over certain algebras or other situations where nice modules appear?